# Backgroundworker alternative for threading - Less CPU Usage?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, cpu, backgroundworker

I've been programming with VB.Net for some time now and when I want to run multiple tasks at the same time that shouldn't freeze my program interface I always use backgroundworkers.

But they often need a lot of CPU. With 5 backgroundworkers at the same time I have partly 100% cpu load depending on which tasks they are doing.

Now I heard from a friend that he is programming similar things like I do and uses "Task Threading" or "Tasks" or something like that in C# which uses only 1% cpu per task instead of 20% cpu like I have in vb.net with Backgroundworkers.

Is there something like "Task Threading" in vb.net? What other threading/multi-threading options do I have besides the background worker which uses less cpu?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If the threads use less CPU% then they will take longer to finish. Is that acceptable?

Comment: The TPL (Tasks Parallel Library) is part of .NET so it is equally available to VB and C#. Your question is like asking whether there's something like WinForms in VB.

Comment: There's a certain overhead involved in using a `BackgroundWorker` so they are not something that you should be using lots of at the same time but they make use of the `ThreadPool` for background work and that is exactly what the TPL will use as well. There's no way that you could do the same work in the same amount of time and that much less CPU utilisation.

Comment: BackgroundWorker is in effect a background thread.  If you're experiencing high CPU usage via background workers, switching to Tasks and the like you might see some improvement, but likely pretty small differences